# Move some files of plugin to the root directory with plugin activation

Tags: plugin-development

I want to move some plugins files to the root directory of the website after plugin activation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no safe way to do that, and even if you succeed, you will cause a lot of trouble for your users.

- The root directory for the web site is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. You might not have write access here, because that can, and maybe should, be turned off.
- WordPress might be installed in a subdirectory; now it's unclear what the "root" is from your point of view.
- There might be other files with the same name already in that place, because your plugin might be active in some sites of a multisite, or one WP installation is used for multiple, separate sites.

If you need an address on the root level, use one of the better options:

- register an endpoint
- use a page template
- hook into `template_redirect` to deliver your custom code

Comment: Root directory like https://example.com

Comment: @HeroWeb512 That's an URL, not a directory.

Comment: i mean to say that i want to add files in main directory like example.com/custom.js

Comment: @HeroWeb512 Why? Sounds like a xy-problem.